# Use a list to initiate a class item in python

Tags: python

So I have a function that can take any number of lists as arguments. With each list, I want to initiate a class object. How do I unwrap the list so I can pass it straight in to the object creation?

```
list_of_routes = []

class Rope_route():
    def __init__(self, setter, color, grade):
        self.setter = setter
        self.color = color
        self.grade = grade


def set_route(*args)
    #each arg should be [setter, color, grade]
    for item in args
        list_of_routes.append(Rope_route(item))

set_route(['jimmy','green','v1'],['jonny','blue','v0'])
```

Is there a better way to solve this than by doing the following?

```
def __init__(self, args_as_list)
    self.setter = args_as_list[0]
    self.color = args_as_list[1]
    self.grade = args_as_list[2]
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand a list as arguments using `*`, e.g.:

```
def set_route(*args):
    #each arg should be [setter, color, grade]
    return [Rope_route(*item) for item in args]


list_of_routes = set_route(...)
```

Note: it is better to return a value rather than modify a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
def __init__(self, args_as_list):
    self.setter, self.color, self.grade = args_as_list
```